# Which file in a jar reads arguments

Tags: java, jar

If I have a jar file which accepts command line arguments, how can I find out which file inside this jar is using these command line arguments?

Comment: Probably whichever file `main()` is located? If `main` passes them off to other classes though, it probably would be nearly impossible to track down without having the source code.

Comment: Jar is in zip-format, so you can open it with WinZip or any other unzipper. Then look in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF where for the line Main-Class: .... you find the class. In that class the `public static void main(String[] args)` is called.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)#Executable_JAR_files), an executable JAR file will have something like

```
Main-Class: myPrograms.MyClass
```

in its `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file.

Answer (score 0):

The class with the main method receive the arguments.
If in the project has many classes with main methods, the class specified in the `MANIFEST.MF` will be the main class to receive the arguments.